# Tracking changes to posts

Tags: database, database-design, sql-server

I'm currently in the process of writing a support ticket system... Let's say it's a small forum application, or something like Uservoice.

Now I want my users to be able to edit their tickets, but still be able to see the old versions of them.

Which route should I take in terms of Database-Design?

I've thought of something like:

SupportTickets

- Identifier
- Author
- Subject
- SupportTicketContentId

SupportTicketContents

- Identifier
- Content
- CreatedOn

Now when viewing a ticket, I'd simply query the most recent `SupportTicketContent` depending on the `CreatedOn` column...

But is there a better way? Or is there a better naming of these tables?

Comment: Support tickets usually contain a lot of meta data - who placed opened the ticket, when, which product/product group the ticket is for, the current status of the ticket, etc.  In some cases you might see dozens of fields!  Would you lump all of that into `SupportTicketContent`?

Comment: @DanPichelman Well... Yes. So you could keep track of what has been changed.

Comment: I would not re-invent the wheel and take the open-source project and tune it under the requirements of the project.

Comment: @ElYusubov We've already tried that, but none of them suited our needs in a grade that would allow us to simply "fine tune" it. All of our tuning of existing projects would result in not quite less hours than writing one - specifically for our needs - from scratch.

Comment: @SeToY it is true that there is no silver bullet solution for the specific needs of each individual tracking system. However, picking one with a growing community support, contributing and customizing to that solution as needed probably is a good decision in long run.

Comment: This is often called row versioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/how-to-version-control-a-record-in-a-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and its database design you have a ticket, a journal item, and any details associated with that.

```
 +--------------+     +----------------+   +----------------+
 | ticket       |     | journal        |   | journal_details|
 |--------------|     |----------------|   |----------------|
 | id           +-+   | id             +-+ | id             |
 | author       | +---+ ticket_id      | +-+ journal_id     |
 | subject      |     | author         |   | field          |
 | priority     |     | timestamp      |   | new_value      |
 | ...          |     | notes          |   | old_value      |
 |              |     |                |   |                |
 +--------------+     +----------------+   +----------------+
```

You don't copy the entire issue each time, but rather you keep all of the 'header' and meta data information up to date in the `ticket` table.

Then, for updates to it (additional notes and any field changes) you create a row in the journal table.  If all you did was add notes, you just add a journal entry.  If, however, a field changed (like the priority) a journal entry row is added, and a journal_detail row for each row changed.

Say you have ticket #123 and you:

- Add notes ('this is actually bar')
- Change the subject from 'foo' to 'bar'
- Change the priority from 'critical' to 'low'

The following things would happen:

- Journal row is added with with the author as you, timestamp as now, ticket_id as 123, and the notes as 'this is actually bar'.  Lets say this row has an ID of 456.
- A journal_detail row is added with jounral_id of 456, field of 'subject' new_value of 'bar', old_value of 'foo'
- A journal_detail row is added with journal_id of 456, field of 'priority' new value of 'low', old value of 'critical'
- Ticket is updated with subject of 'bar' and priority of 'low'

This way, if needed, one could reconstruct the past and see who did what when.  But few people want to see what it *really* looks like a month ago - they want fast queries and displays against current data.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Honestly, creating a new ticket tracking system from the scratch is tempting and cool! However, I would try stay away from **re-inventing** the wheel.

One of the good approaches would be clarifying all business requirements and look for available open-source alternatives. Here you are several alternatives to start with:

- [ASP.net based open source support ticket system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1748247/1437962)
- [BugTracker.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/btnet/?source=directory)
- [Slick-ticket.com/](http://slick-ticket.com/)
- [Ticket Desk](http://ticketdesk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Bad answer, well intended, understandable but a bad answer to the question as asked.

Comment: @Murph it is a specific point of view to the problem, and question. It is the solution to the problem with alternatives, and not just an answer.

Comment: Erm... the comment to that effect is perfectly reasonable - but remove the context from the question and you still have a decent question which you don't address. So its a discussion about something that is not the question not really answer at all.

Comment: Have to agree with Murph. Nothing in the question indicates  this is being deployed within a div team. This could be a project or a new app. Plenty in this space, but everything can be improved.